# How to apply the same classList.remove function to multiple different IDs

Tags: javascript

I am very new to programming and am trying to create a text based rpg. Right now I have multiple functions toggling the visibility of different div elements based on their individual IDs. I can't make them all the same ID or else all the choices for the entire story would be shown to them when they click the start button. Can I create just one function that performs only on the ID called on? Any help or resources to learn how to understand your answers would be amazing!
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to:

> *I can't make them all the same ID*

You cannot reuse an ID in an HTML page anyways. Each ID on a document must be unique. You could always add a class or data-attribute to each element to logically group them for batch operations.

---

### Enter, document.querySelectorAll

You can select on a list of selectors (IDs):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#btn-1, #btn-2, #btn-3, #btn-4, #btn-5')
  .forEach(btn => {
    btn.classList.remove('remove-me');
  });
```

```css
.remove-me { background: red; }
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" class="remove-me">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-2" class="remove-me">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-3" class="remove-me">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-4" class="remove-me">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-5" class="remove-me">Button #1</button>
```

Or, you can select by a class:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
  .forEach(btn => {
    btn.classList.remove('remove-me');
  });
```

```css
.remove-me { background: red; }
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" class="btn remove-me">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-2" class="btn remove-me">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-3" class="btn remove-me">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-4" class="btn remove-me">Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-5" class="btn remove-me">Button #1</button>
```

Or, by a data-attribute:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-special-button]')
  .forEach(btn => {
    btn.classList.remove('remove-me');
  });
```

```css
.remove-me { background: red; }
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" class="remove-me" data-special-button>Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-2" class="remove-me" data-special-button>Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-3" class="remove-me" data-special-button>Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-4" class="remove-me" data-special-button>Button #1</button>
<button id="btn-5" class="remove-me" data-special-button>Button #1</button>
```